# add a path to the PATH environmental variable using CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to modify the environmental variable PATH so that it contains an extra `\bin` folder so the modification is seen globally (outside the cmake environment). I was trying the following:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(change_path ALL COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env PATH="${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/../bin:$ENV{PATH})
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: **Child** process (`cmake` execution) **cannot modify environment** for **parent** process (which calls `cmake`). 'env' command for `cmake -E` mode modifies environment only for the commands, executed in that mode. The only way for *child* process to modify *parent*'s environment is a modification of some "profile" files, and asking the *parent* to reload values from that profile. This is done in OS-specific way and CMake doesn't provide interface for that.

Comment: I have found an executable in a computer, I have created a symbolic link I can use to execute that program, but now I need to add the path to my PATH environmental variable. Is there any way I can do this with CMake?

Comment: `Is there any way I can do this with CMake?` - Generally, not. Using CMake, you may run any program. But creating a program for environment modification is not a CMake question. However, you may use CMake for run your executable with modified environment.

Comment: I'm wondering if you know that the `-E env`  does take a `COMMAND` to be executed with the modified environment?

Comment: You cannot modify the path to processes superior to `cmake`, only subprocesses of `cmake`

Comment: Just a thought: Is this for having the program installed? Use `make install` and set e.g. [`CPACK_NSIS_MODIFY_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPackNSIS.html#variable:CPACK_NSIS_MODIFY_PATH): "Modify PATH toggle. If this is set to `ON`, then an extra page will appear in the installer that will allow the user to choose whether the program directory should be added to the system PATH variable." Would that solve your problem? What OSs are you targeting?

Comment: I'm targeting Linux and Mac OS. It's not for install, but during the build I would like to do this. The path to the build directory should be added.

Comment: would this be effectively solved by using `cmake --install` to install the built project onto your system?